# Extracting the third part of a string to a new column only if it exists

Tags: r, string, dplyr, extract, tidyr

I have data as follows:

## Data

```
library(dplyr)
dat_in_one <- structure(list(rn = c("Type_A", "Type_B"
), `[0,25)` = c(5L, 0L), `[25,50)` = c(0L, 0L), `[25,100)` = c(38L, 
3L), `[50,100)` = c(0L, 0L), `[100,250)` = c(43L, 5L), `[100,500)` = c(0L, 
0L), `[250,500)` = c(27L, 12L), `[500,1000)` = c(44L, 0L), `[1000,1500)` = c(0L, 
0L), `[1500,3000)` = c(0L, 0L), `[500,1000000]` = c(0L, 53L), 
    `[1000,1000000]` = c(20L, 0L), `[3000,1000000]` = c(0L, 0L
    ), Sum_bin = c(177, 73), strata = list(c(0, 25, 100, 250, 
    500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 250, 500, 1e+06))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

```
library(dplyr)
dat_in_two <- structure(list(rn = c("Type_A", "Type_B"
), `[0,25) East` = c(5L, 0L), `[25,50) South` = c(0L, 0L), `[25,100) West` = c(38L, 
3L), `[50,100) North` = c(0L, 0L), `[100,250) East` = c(43L, 5L), `[100,500) South` = c(0L, 
0L), `[250,500) South` = c(27L, 12L), `[500,1000) South` = c(44L, 0L), `[1000,1500) South` = c(0L, 
0L), `[1500,3000) South` = c(0L, 0L), `[500,1000000] East` = c(0L, 53L), 
    `[1000,1000000] South` = c(20L, 0L), `[3000,1000000] South` = c(0L, 0L
    ), Sum_bin = c(177, 73), strata = list(c(0, 25, 100, 250, 
    500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 250, 500, 1e+06))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

## Issue

I would like to adapt this piece of code below (which extracts the numbers from the `strata` column and creates two new columns from it):

```
dat_in_one %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(rn, strata)) %>%
  extract(name, c('lower', 'upper'), '(\\d+),(\\d+)', convert = TRUE)


# A tibble: 28 x 5
   rn     strata    lower upper value
   <chr>  <list>    <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 Type_A <dbl [7]>     0    25     5
 2 Type_A <dbl [7]>    25    50     0
 3 Type_A <dbl [7]>    25   100    38
 4 Type_A <dbl [7]>    50   100     0
 5 Type_A <dbl [7]>   100   250    43
 6 Type_A <dbl [7]>   100   500     0
# ... with 22 more rows
```

It currently ignores the terms `East`, `South` etc in `dat_in_two`. I would like to try to adapt this code, to work on both `dat_in_one` and `dat_in_two`, where for `dat_in_two` it creates a third column. I tried to do, but it does not work at all.

```
dat_in_two %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(rn, strata)) %>%
  extract(name, c('lower', 'upper', 'the_rest'), '(\\d+),(\\d+),(\\w+)', convert = TRUE)
```

## Desired outcome for dat_in_one

```
# A tibble: 28 x 5
   rn     strata    lower upper value
   <chr>  <list>    <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 Type_A <dbl [7]>     0    25     5
 2 Type_A <dbl [7]>    25    50     0
 3 Type_A <dbl [7]>    25   100    38
 4 Type_A <dbl [7]>    50   100     0
 5 Type_A <dbl [7]>   100   250    43
 6 Type_A <dbl [7]>   100   500     0
# ... with 22 more rows
```

## Desired outcome for dat_in_two

```
# A tibble: 28 x 5
   rn     strata    lower upper rest  value
   <chr>  <list>    <int> <int> <char> <dbl>
 1 Type_A <dbl [7]>     0    25 East      5
 2 Type_A <dbl [7]>    25    50 South     0
 3 Type_A <dbl [7]>    25   100 West     38
 4 Type_A <dbl [7]>    50   100 North     0
 5 Type_A <dbl [7]>   100   250 East     43
 6 Type_A <dbl [7]>   100   500 South     0
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```r
dat_in_one <- structure(list(rn = c("Type_A", "Type_B"
), `[0,25)` = c(5L, 0L), `[25,50)` = c(0L, 0L), `[25,100)` = c(38L, 
                                                               3L), `[50,100)` = c(0L, 0L), `[100,250)` = c(43L, 5L), `[100,500)` = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                      0L), `[250,500)` = c(27L, 12L), `[500,1000)` = c(44L, 0L), `[1000,1500)` = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0L), `[1500,3000)` = c(0L, 0L), `[500,1000000]` = c(0L, 53L), 
`[1000,1000000]` = c(20L, 0L), `[3000,1000000]` = c(0L, 0L
), Sum_bin = c(177, 73), strata = list(c(0, 25, 100, 250, 
                                         500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 250, 500, 1e+06))), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                            -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

dat_in_two <- structure(list(rn = c("Type_A", "Type_B"
), `[0,25) East` = c(5L, 0L), `[25,50) South` = c(0L, 0L), `[25,100) West` = c(38L, 
                                                                               3L), `[50,100) North` = c(0L, 0L), `[100,250) East` = c(43L, 5L), `[100,500) South` = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       0L), `[250,500) South` = c(27L, 12L), `[500,1000) South` = c(44L, 0L), `[1000,1500) South` = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0L), `[1500,3000) South` = c(0L, 0L), `[500,1000000] East` = c(0L, 53L), 
`[1000,1000000] South` = c(20L, 0L), `[3000,1000000] South` = c(0L, 0L
), Sum_bin = c(177, 73), strata = list(c(0, 25, 100, 250, 
                                         500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 250, 500, 1e+06))), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                            -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

is_all_na <- function(x)all(is.na(x))

dat_in_two %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(rn, strata)) %>%
  extract(name, c('lower', 'upper', 'rest'), '(\\d+),(\\d+)[\\]\\)]\\s*(\\w*)', convert = TRUE)  %>% 
  select(-where(is_all_na))
#> # A tibble: 28 × 6
#>    rn     strata    lower upper rest  value
#>    <chr>  <list>    <int> <int> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 Type_A <dbl [7]>     0    25 East      5
#>  2 Type_A <dbl [7]>    25    50 South     0
#>  3 Type_A <dbl [7]>    25   100 West     38
#>  4 Type_A <dbl [7]>    50   100 North     0
#>  5 Type_A <dbl [7]>   100   250 East     43
#>  6 Type_A <dbl [7]>   100   500 South     0
#>  7 Type_A <dbl [7]>   250   500 South    27
#>  8 Type_A <dbl [7]>   500  1000 South    44
#>  9 Type_A <dbl [7]>  1000  1500 South     0
#> 10 Type_A <dbl [7]>  1500  3000 South     0
#> # … with 18 more rows

dat_in_one %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(rn, strata)) %>%
  extract(name, c('lower', 'upper', 'rest'), '(\\d+),(\\d+)[\\]\\)]\\s*(\\w*)', convert = TRUE)  %>% 
  select(-where(is_all_na))
#> # A tibble: 28 × 5
#>    rn     strata    lower upper value
#>    <chr>  <list>    <int> <int> <dbl>
#>  1 Type_A <dbl [7]>     0    25     5
#>  2 Type_A <dbl [7]>    25    50     0
#>  3 Type_A <dbl [7]>    25   100    38
#>  4 Type_A <dbl [7]>    50   100     0
#>  5 Type_A <dbl [7]>   100   250    43
#>  6 Type_A <dbl [7]>   100   500     0
#>  7 Type_A <dbl [7]>   250   500    27
#>  8 Type_A <dbl [7]>   500  1000    44
#>  9 Type_A <dbl [7]>  1000  1500     0
#> 10 Type_A <dbl [7]>  1500  3000     0
#> # … with 18 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>